# Image coordinates link click alert message show

Tags: javascript, html, image, coordinates

When i click Image coordinates alert message show.

**For Example:** This is my picture
[image]

If i click `cycle seat` show `alert` like **"You are click cycle seat"**

```
    <img src="https://www.bricklanebikes.co.uk/content/images/thumbs/0021232_6ku-fixie-single-speed-bike-beach-bum_1200.jpeg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="Cycle Seat" href="cycle-seat.html" shape="poly" coords="329,146,364,162,394,171,442,164,490,168,520,171,506,154,479,146,373,139,347,132,336,132,331,141,330,138" />
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/qwzh4vgh/

Comment: What is your question? What isn’t working?

Comment: Am creating a coords using thhis link http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/

Comment: when i clicking cycle seat showing some alert @Xufox

Comment: See this example https://jsfiddle.net/qwzh4vgh/ @Xufox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to show some alert box when you are clicking on the area inside the image map. [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978103/determine-which-area-in-a-map-imagemap-was-clicked-using-javascript-or-jquery) which can help you to do that.

Example code using jQuery:

`$("map#Map area").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('title')); 
});`

Here is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2gax7Le/).